# How to make a JSON object out of a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'me new to JavaScript. In the browser I receive a long dictionary like this:

```
{"cat": "4" , "dog": "5", "fish": "9" }
```

I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to convert it to a JSON object like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "cat",
    "value": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "dog",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "name": "fish",
    "value": "9"
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Please post what you've tried

Comment: Uh ... You simply can't. There's no dictionary [objects] in JS, see also [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried to iterate over the dictionary but failed.

Comment: @Teemu so what can I do to make the later out of the former?

Comment: The desired output is invalid, further, there is nothing called JSON object in Javascript.

Comment: This format is incorrect

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? If yes, which one, on which line, what does it say? Also, please clarify your question. The output you posted is not valid JSON, so what *is* the output you want?

Comment: @Ele, sorry I modifed the JSON output that I'm intended to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Loop through it and push each key-value-pair to an Array.

```js
var tValue = {"cat": "4" , "dog": "5", "fish": "9" };
var tList = [];

for(var tKey in tValue) tList.push({name: tKey, value: tValue[tKey]});

console.log(tList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop over the dictionary object keys using **[`Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**, and use [**`.map()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each iterated key/value pair to the appropriate `object`:

```
var results = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
  return {
    name: k,
    value: obj[k]
  };
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var obj = {
  "cat": "4",
  "dog": "5",
  "fish": "9"
};

var results = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
  return {
    name: k,
    value: obj[k]
  };
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: @Babr Yes, of course, just check the MDN reference for each method, you will see that they're compatible with almost all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Object.entries` to get every key-value pairs and with the function `map` build the desired output.

```js
let obj = {"cat": "4" , "dog": "5", "fish": "9" },
    result = Object.entries(obj).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by this way :

- Call a for in loop and read your first object
- Push the name and the value in your new object one by one..
  Sample code :

```js
var a = {"cat": "4" , "dog": "5", "fish": "9" };
var newJSON = [] ;
console.log(a);


for ( key in a ) {
  newJSON.push({name : key, value : a[key]});
 }

console.log(newJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this kind of formatted object

```
{
    animals : [
        {"name":"cat", "value": 4},
        {"name":"dog", "value": 5},
        {"name":"fish", "value": 9}
    ]
}
```

or like this

```
[
   {"name":"cat", "value": 4},
   {"name":"dog", "value": 5},
   {"name":"fish", "value": 9}
]
```